# Can I run a command of symfony from the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I am making something like a forum in symfony where people can make stories in common, a bit like a roleplaying game.

When someone is showing that one character is talking the line will be shown with a font and color set by the owner of the character. So  I write a sentence, select it and press a button with the name of the character, and internally wraps that sentence in a span with a classname that is the name of the character, so when the css reads that line it is formated.

Now the problem I have, my idea is that the owner of the character can modify the font or the style, so when I do that the controller generates a css file named like the character in a special folder. Then I can use the [assetic component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) from symfony to load all the css files from that folder. The problem is that if I want to use them in production I need to run a special command from symfony (php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug).

The question now is, can I run that command from the controller? I guess not for security reasons.

I know that I can always make just one css with all the classes of the characters, but I would need to parse the file looking for the class and modifying it instead of just overwrite the file and let symfony do the rest.

If it isn't possible do you know someway my idea could be "easily" done?

Hi hope you can understand me, thanks

Comment: this article might help you:
https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/console/command_in_controller.html

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. It says it could not find the assetic namespace, when it is installed. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands from your PHP using the `exec()` function from php. I think there is probably a more clean and secure way to achieve what your trying to do, but regarding running commands with php, you can use `exec()`. Good luck with your project. Sounds cool.

Comment: I tried that, it's strange, the output of the command says the file was created but the file don't exists in the folder. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You will find everything you need in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html).

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I did the example of the documentation and it says "[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] There are no commands defined in the "swiftmailer:spool" namespace. ". The same with the assetic command.

Comment: /**
 * @Route("/testassetdump", name="asset")
 */
public function assetAction()
{
 $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
 $application = new Application($kernel);
 $application->setAutoExit(false);

 $input = new ArrayInput(array(
  'command' => 'assetic:dump',
  '--env' => 'prod'
 ));

 $output = new BufferedOutput();

 $application->run($input, $output);
 $content = $output->fetch();

 dump($content);
 return new Response('<html><body>'.$content.'</body></html>');
}

Comment: It works, the output you get is '<html><body>Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is on.</body></html>' this the output of the command not the result of what was generated by assetic. Or I don't understand what you try to do.